# Sending data to another view controller

Tags: ios, swift

This is a learning app that I am making for fun, I have been stuck here for 2 days.

I have two views setup that I use to send data that the user will pick to the other one (they are named AddCoinVC and MainVC).

In AddCoinVC, the sending is performed when the user clicks on the button

```
let vc = MainViewController()
vc.coinArray.append(CoinWallet(coinName: "Test", coinSymbol: "Test", coinAmount: "0"))
performSegue(withIdentifier: "backToMain", sender: self)
```

I have setup a breakpoint at this point and printing `vc.coinArray` prints me the correct value =

> ($R0 = 1 value { (coinName = "Test", coinSymbol = "Test", coinAmount = "0")
>   }

But when I go to my other breakpoint at MainVC, it displays 0 value.

```
var coinArray = [CoinWallet]()
```

This is the var that I use, the default in MainVC is CoinWallet which is empty when first loading the app. This is the custom Class.

```
class CoinWallet {
    var coinName:String = ""
    var coinSymbol:String = ""
    var coinAmount:String = ""

    init(coinName: String, coinSymbol:String, coinAmount: String) {
        self.coinName = coinName
        self.coinSymbol = coinSymbol
        self.coinAmount = coinAmount
    }
}
```

When the segue and the sending is performed from AddCoinVC to MainVC 'coinArray' should have this value sent to it.

Why would be the value empty if vc.coinArray has 1 value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error occurs because `MainViewController()` does not return the view controller you expect. It's a new blank instance which is not the instance in the storyboard.

Since you are performing a segue anyway, pass the `CoinWallet` instance as `sender` parameter in `performSegue`

```
let coin = CoinWallet(coinName: "Test", coinSymbol: "Test", coinAmount: "0")
performSegue(withIdentifier: "backToMain", sender: coin)
```

Then implement `prepare(for segue` and use the `destination` property as reference to the main view controller.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "backToMain" { 
       let coin = sender as! CoinWallet
       let mainViewController = segue.destination as! MainViewController
       mainViewController.coinArray.append(coin)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add this method in your `AddCoinVC` and send data as below,

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let mainVC = segue.destination as? MainViewController {
        mainVC.coinArray.append(CoinWallet(coinName: "Test", coinSymbol: "Test", coinAmount: "0"))
    }
}
```

In the below lines of code, you are just creating a new instance that is not the `viewController` being segued.

```
let vc = MainViewController()
vc.coinArray.append(CoinWallet(coinName: "Test", coinSymbol: "Test", coinAmount: "0"))
```

You should only perform the `segue` on `button` click as below and set any data inside the above method.

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "backToMain", sender: self)
```